# Thread.Join UI block in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I created a custom `MessageWindow` in order to get rid of the old one and put my own style on it...

My problem is when I for example click a button to open the custom `MessageWindow` it doesn't really block my UI.

```
public static void Show(string caption, string message)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        MessageWindow window = new MessageWindow(caption, message);
        window.ShowDialog();
    });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}
```

I thought `thread.Join` will block the parent thread until the new one is gone, but somehow the UI is partially active. I don't see animations nor I'm able to move the window but when I click a button on the blocked thread while my `MessageWindow` is open it still accept the click and perform it after I closed the `MessageWindow` thread.

Is there any way to **disable** the message pump or block/lock any threads/UI when the message window is open?

Comment: Here's a novel idea - try some debugging.  Put a breakpoint on the Join() and see when it is reached.

Comment: thread.join will block the parent thread but still allows message pumping - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TheLonelyCoder A very unexpected quirk that could bite you when you WANT to block the UI thread. Same with `MessageBox.Show`. `Monitor.Wait()` seems to be "truly" blocking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new thread for the other window. When using WPF, all UI should run on the same thread.

Create new threads when you want to do something that is unrelated to UI and don't want to block the UI.

Comment: Heh - true, but I suspect that the OP problem will remain :(

Comment: @MartinJames I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the user from interacting with the main window while a `MessageWindow` is visible, simply set the `Owner` of the `MessageWindow` to your application's main window.  Then call `ShowDialog()` from the UI thread, and the behavior should be comparable to if you called `MessageBox.Show()`.

Do not use a separate thread or attempt to manually block the message pump.